# Is it possible to use crosstalk with kableextra table?

Tags: r, filter, widget, flexdashboard, kableextra

I've formatted my table nicely using `kableextra` and I want to apply a `crosstalk` `filter_slider` to one of the columns so that the user can adjust it. However, I am getting the following error:

> Error in if (nrow(df) > 0) as.character(1:nrow(df)) else character() : argument is of length zero

The code works fine if the table is not formatted using `kableextra`. How can I fix this? Here is some basic reproducible code I put together to demonstrate:

```
Name <- c("Dwyer, Andy","Ludgate, April", "Knope, Leslie")
Rank <- c(1,2,3)
Hours <- c(1000,2000,5000)
Title <- c("Shoe Shine","Intern","Deputy Director")
df <- data.frame(Name,Rank,Title, Hours)

library(crosstalk)
df2 <- SharedData$new(df)
filter_slider("Rank","Top",df2,column=~Rank)

library(kableExtra)
df3 <- kable(df,row.names=FALSE) %>%
   kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped","hover",full_width=T),fixed_thead = T)%>%row_spec(seq(1,nrow(df),2),background = "aliceblue")

df3

df4 <- SharedData$new(df3)
filter_slider("Rank","Top",df4,column=~Rank)
```

I expect the `filter_slider` to work on both tables without error. I need an interactive filter to work on the `kable` formatted table and cannot use `shiny`.